# Vue reactive object containing array of object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have tried many different formats, but can only make this work:

```
// This works
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { IPixabayItem } from '../interfaces/IPixapayItem'
const imageList: IPixabayItem[] = []
const foundImages = reactive(
    {
        images: imageList
    }
)
</script>
```

Somehow I would like to avoid the const 'imageList' and instantiate the 'IPixabayItem[]' inside the reactive object; but cannot make this transpile.

```
// This dosn't work
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { IPixabayItem } from '../interfaces/IPixapayItem'
const foundImages = reactive(
    {
        images: IPixabayItem[] = []
    }
)
</script>
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an empty array as the value for `images` and set `IPixabayItem[]` as the generic parameter of `reactive`.

```
const foundImages = reactive<{images: IPixabayItem[]}>({
    images: []
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgQwMY2ANxXAXzgDMoIQ4ByHAVxUoCgHgA7GFKYzfASQAVgADzQAjNAE8e7CggZx5cNAC44AZxhRWAcwYEmGCC3UkINFgBMeINFpSq4AXmTosuFAB4EoG3ZX8hohJSKCAA2gC6BAB8ABSyCnDetqoqEboAlEA)

---

or you could use the `as` keyword:

```
const foundImages = reactive({
    images: [] as IPixabayItem[]
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgQwMY2ANxXAXzgDMoIQ4ByHAVxUoCgHgA7GFKYzfASQAVgADzQAjNAE8e7CggZx5cNAC44AZxhRWAcwYEmGCC3UkINFgBMeINFpSq4AXmTosuFAApZCuKBt2VANoAuor2-EKiElIoIMG6AJRAA)

Comment: Wow, Thanks Tobis S.

Your idea seems to work !!

..hmm Sorry my formating. I'm newbee in making posts in stackocerflow :-(

`<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { IPixabayItem } from '../interfaces/IPixapayItem'
const foundImages = reactive(
    {
    images: [] as IPixabayItem[]
    }
)
</script>
`

Comment: Hi Tobias
Sorry my misspelling of Tobias (and stackoverflow) but you deserve a "tumps up" for your great reply; which I cannot give :-(

Stackoverflow "Tumps up" reply:
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

/erm2000